# Config specific to environment in Octopus Deploy

Tags: .net-core, octopus-deploy

I have a set of configs in my .net core app:

```
appsettings.config
appsettings.environment1.config
appsettings.environment2.config
```

I'd like to be able to use app.config as a base config and apply one more config based on the current environment. Something like this:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true);
```

The challenge here is how to get the environment under which this app was deployed. Keeping it in environment variables is not an option as there're multiple environments in one machine. I hope there's a way to somehow "push" environment name to the deployed app's config or something along these lines

Comment: You could use one appsettings.json file and replace each property depending on which environment you deploy to from octopys. Example: "ConnectionString":"#{ConnectionString}", then in your octopus pipeline, add different connectionstrings for each environment

Comment: `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` can be an option

Comment: @SiberianGuy `.config` or `.json`?

Comment: @t-prisar, json

Comment: @t-prisar, what if there're several environments on one machine?

Comment: @SiberianGuy okay